# PHPStorm open index.php in Chrome using live edit?

Tags: browser, live, edit, phpstorm

just got PHPStorm and i am wondering if it is possible to run index.php in chrome using live edit? I managed to get it working with index.html, but php debug just opens the console.
Any tutorials?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you can't live edit PHP is because it is a server-side script, not a client side script like JavaScript. Thus, you will not see live updates in Chrome; you will need to refresh to get updates.

PHPStorm does support debugging PHP, though, just in a different way: 
[JetBrains PHP Debug Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/php-debugging-session.html)

Comment: Yes,but i could see the for example echo 'hi' in browser? Could u please give me a tutorial on how to set everything up?

Comment: So it is not possible to do PHP debuggin in browser? Even with local php server?

Comment: No, because the browser **does not** process PHP! The server does. In that documentation I sent you, you can see the result in the browser, however; you cannot do any sort of manipulation of the PHP from the browser, rather this is done in PHPStorm.

Comment: Yes, i just want to see the result in the browser :D

Comment: Well, I've answered your question then... I linked you to the docs that tell you how to do that.